# Editing button inside <form th:action>

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I have three buttons:

```
 <td>
        <a th:href="@{/appointments/{id}/details(id=${appointment.id})}">View</a> |
        <a th:href="@{/appointments/{id}/edit(id=${appointment.id})}">Edit</a> |
        <form th:action="@{/appointments/{id}/delete(id=${appointment.id})}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
```

`View - Edit` looks nice, and same, but on button `delete` I have some border and its not aligned with those two.

I'm assuming that is because `delete` button is inside form.

What I tried?

First I add class on button like this:
`<button type="submit" class="btn delete-btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')">Delete</button>`

And then `CSS` like this:

```
   .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.delete-btn {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}
```

That was slightly better, but I still have grey border around delete button.
Is there anyway that I can remove it and make delete button in same line as view and edit button?

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please DO not use server templating in your snippet

Comment: Please stop posting those comments. I already visited how to ask, provide a problem, what I tried and what is output, what I need to provide more?

Comment: Please do what I ask so we can help you instead of complaining I ask. You posted some snippets of CSS and some images. Just please post the RELEVANT HTML and CSS and if needed a framework in a ***[mcve]*** like I ask and you will get an answer in a minute instead of getting voted down and closed.

Comment: go watch some fun cat videos and free pressure, you are so mad bro XD

Comment: and I'll provide answer `form{ border:none;` thanks, so hard to do..

Comment: I am not mad at all. You are just disrespecting my attempts to help you. You are not a noob here, so be nice.

Comment: Also a right-click on a rendered page would have shown it was not the button that had a border immediately so I could have answered that 30 minutes ago even with 0 knowledge of thymeleaf. But without rendered HTML, I could not be certain..."I have 3 buttons" nope. You have two links and a button in a form with a border